# Can't update a single value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

After creating a dictionary like `{'key': {'key': {'key': 'value'}}}`, I ran into issues trying to set the value for the higher depth key. After updating one of these values, the values for the remainder values (of other keys) were also updated.

Here's my Python code:

```
times = ["09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30"]
courts = ["1", "2"]

daytime_dict = dict.fromkeys(times)
i = 0
for time in times:
    daytime_dict[times[i]] = dict.fromkeys(["username"])
    i += 1

courts_dict = dict.fromkeys(courts)
k = 0
for court in courts:
    courts_dict[courts[k]] = daytime_dict
    k += 1

day_info = [('name', '09:00', 1), ('name', '09:30', 1)]
for info in day_info:
    info_court = str(info[2])
    time = info[1]
    # Here I am trying to set the value for courts_dict['1']['09:00']["username"] to be 'name', 
    # but the value for courts_dict['2']['09:00']["username"] and courts_dict['3']['09:00']["username"] is also set to 'name'
    # What am I doing wrong? How can I only update the value for where the court is '1'?
    courts_dict[info_court][time]["username"] = info[0]
```

I desire to get this:

```
{'1': {'09:00': {'username': 'name'},
       '09:30': {'username': 'name'},
       '10:00': {'username': None},
       '10:30': {'username': None}},
 '2': {'09:00': {'username': None},
       '09:30': {'username': None},
       '10:00': {'username': None},
       '10:30': {'username': None}}
```

But I'm getting this:

```
{'1': {'09:00': {'username': 'name'},
       '09:30': {'username': 'name'},
       '10:00': {'username': None},
       '10:30': {'username': None}},
 '2': {'09:00': {'username': 'name'},
       '09:30': {'username': 'name'},
       '10:00': {'username': None},
       '10:30': {'username': None}}
```

(See how `court_dict['2']['09:00']['username']` and `court_dict['2']['09:30']['username']` are both being updated when I only wish to update values from `court_dict['1']`)

Logically, I can't understand why both values are updated when I update the `courts_dict` (how I did in the last line of code), and not just one. Since `info_court` is `"1"`, I thought only the `"username"` for that court would be updated.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: you are likely referencing a dictionary as opposed to making a copy.

Comment: try this and see if the problem goes away `courts_dict[courts[k]] = daytime_dict.copy()`

Comment: It didn't work, I got the same results as before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Logically, I can't understand why both values are updated when I update the courts_dict

For the dictionary objects you are using you are assigning the same object *references* as values, hence why you are seeing "both values are updated". You may want to rework your code using `copy` or `deepcopy`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.